# How Can I Improve Function to Use In PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, function, sql-injection

, i'm trying to prevent SQL Injection
, is my function enough when I'm using MySQL? How can I improve it?

Thanks for your time and patience.

```
    <?php
    function sanitize($data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach($data as $var=>$val) {
                $output[$var] = sanitize($val);
            }
         }
         else {
             if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                 $data = stripslashes($data);
             }
             $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
             $output = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
         }
         return $output;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfect example of what you should never ever use in your code. The rules are very simple:

a) Use prepared statements (I highly recommend this solution)

or (if for some reason you cannot use PDO or mysqli)

b.1) **Every** (even the one you got from "trusted" source, **without any exceptions**) string that acts as a value should be `mysql_real_escape_string`ed
b.2) every integer should be `(int)`ed
b.3) every number that is not integer should be checked if it is what it is expected
b.4) never use user's input as a substitution for column/table names, always use whitelists

As simple as 1-2-3

So you apply the sanitizing function only when you need it - you never apply some "universal" function to all variables you have

> How can I improve it?

The only way to improve it - is to delete it

**UPD**:

What is whitelist - let's say you accept user input to use as a column name. For example for sorting facilities.

So you need to create `array('col1', 'col2')` and check if user's input presents in this array (so called whitelist). If it does - you can use it, otherwise - you wouldn't do that

Comment: When you say I should never use user's input as a substitution for column/
table names, always use whitelists. Please what do you regard as whitlist? Or in what cases could this occur.?

I have a portion of my script where by I have ..... SELECT first_name AS 'ALIAS' ....... Is this an example?

Thanks you.